# Uncheck UITableview custom checkbox option in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox

I am trying to make a custom checkbox list using the UITableview that allows single selections (I should however be able to select as many options as I want) and a custom UITableCell.

My custom cell contains a Label and an ImageView and all I want is to change the image contained in the IV on tap.

I am able to change the image from unchecked to checked in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath without a problem but I am having problems changing it back from checked to unchecked.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    print("tableView -> didSelectRowAtIndexPath")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellVC

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "CheckedBox")
}
```

I tried to play with the highlighted state of the ImageView by adding the checkedbox image as the highlighted image and then turning it on and off but it only enters the if but ignores the if else if clicked again

```
    if(cell.ivCellImage.highlighted == false)
    {
        print("Highligth is OFF")
        cell.ivCellImage.highlighted = true
    }
    else if(cell.ivCellImage.highlighted == true)
    {
        print("Highligth is ON")
        cell.ivCellImage.highlighted = false
    }
```

as well as checking what image is inside the IV, this if-else block being completely ignored

```
    if(cell.ivRiskCellImage.image!.isEqual(UIImage(named: "UncheckedBox")))
    {
        print("Is unchecked!")
        cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "CheckedBox")
    }
    else if(cell.ivRiskCellImage.image!.isEqual(UIImage(named: "CheckedBox")))
    {
        print("Is checked!")
        cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UnheckedBox")
    }
```

Moreover, when I manage to display the checkedbox image on click I get something like this

[image]

while if I try setting the checked box for all the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath by adding this

```
cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "CheckedBox")
```

the checkbox tick is no longer semitransparent but white, as it should be

[image]

Any ideas? I spent quite some time trying to solve this without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...` I would use

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCellVC
```

This way you get a reference to the cell you want to change the image in. `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is meant to be used in delegate method `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` when you want to recycle your cells for better performance.

Also `cell.ivRiskCellImage.image!.isEqual(UIImage(named: "UncheckedBox"))` doesn't work, because `UIImage(named: "UncheckedBox")` creates a new UIImage, which isn't the same as the UIImage you want to check it against.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with this: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
     {
         let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RiskCustomCellVC
         cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "CheckedBox")
     }
    
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
     {
         let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RiskCustomCellVC
         cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "UncheckedBox")
     }

Comment: Thank you so much! I was doing the same mistake kinda unknowingly and this actually makes so much sense! :)

Answer (score 1):

As fat i understand that you want to change image form Check and Uncheck and vice versa

There is mainly two methods of table view delegate

```
– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

reference link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:

Although you can do same thing in **– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    print("tableView -> didSelectRowAtIndexPath")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCellVC

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.ivRiskCellImage.image = UIImage(named: "**unCheckedBox**")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath without any luck. But after defining my cell as Markus pointed out and allowing multiple selections it seems I am able to select it in didSelect and deselect it in didDeselect.